# ¿Como linkear dentro de tu mismo documento.html usando el patrón template?

Tags: javascript, html, href

Lo que quiero hacer es linkear mi menu con sus respectivas secciones, la problematica es la siguiente, yo genere el patron de diseño template, por lo que separe cada una de las secciones de mi archivo html en unos propios, por lo cual mi archivo principal es la union de los demas documentos.

Código de ejemplo:

```
<body>
<?php include 'HTML/Encabezado.html'; ?>
<br>
<?php include 'HTML/Galeria.html'; ?>
<br>
<div name="videogames">
<?php include 'HTML/Seleccionador.html'; ?> 
</div>
<br>    
<?php include 'HTML/Formulario.html'; ?>
<br>    
<?php include 'HTML/pie.html'; ?>
```

Linkear un mismo documento ya lo habia echo pero no de esta forma y por el momento no me funciona. lo que intente hacer fue lo siguiente:

Aqui agregue el nombre al cual va  hacer referencia mi boton del menu.

```
<div name="videogames">
<?php include 'HTML/Seleccionador.html'; ?> 
</div>
```

Aqui se hace la referencia a dicho div, ambos archivos se ven en un mismo documento pero no estan en el mismo documento.

```
<li><a title="Videojuegos" href="#videogames">Videojuegos</a></li>
```

encabezado.html contiene mi menú y el archivo index.php contiene todos los includes.

Como puedo hacer para que la dar clic en mi menú seleccione y se deslice hacia abajo para visualizar sus componentes, teniendo en cuenta que todos los archivos son separados pero unidos en un mismo documento. Espero me haya explicado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes un ID

```
<li><a title="Videojuegos" href="#videogames">Videojuegos</a></li>
```

Llama a un ID

```
<div id="videogames">
    <?php include 'HTML/Seleccionador.html'; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Como nota, `name` funcionaría con la etiqueta `a` (aunque se considera obsoleto a partir de HTML5, los navegadores siguen soportándolo) pero no con `div` como está en la pregunta.